# Popup widget in qt

Tags: c++, qt, popup, qwidget, qframe

How to create it in qt?

When you click on button - should be shown popup widget and its width should be = button width.
And if main window (main form) drag to another place on the screen - popup widget should continuously follow the button (must be attached to the bottom border of the button).

before click image:
[image: before click image]

after click image:
[image: after click image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create widget, don't put it any layout, set it's parent to button's parent (lets call it "host"), set window flags to `Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint`

```
mPopup = new QWidget(this);
mPopup->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Override host's `resizeEvent` and `moveEvent` and adjust popup's geometry there using button's geometry.

```
void Host::adjustPopup() {
    if (!mPopup->isVisible()) {
        return;
    }
    QRect rect = mButton->geometry();
    QPoint bottomLeft = this->mapToGlobal(rect.bottomLeft());
    mPopup->setGeometry(QRect(bottomLeft, QSize(rect.width(),200)));
}

void Host::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    adjustPopup();
}

void Host::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::moveEvent(event);
    adjustPopup();
}
```

full source: [button-popup](https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/button-popup)